# Wrong order of data when converting a JTable to JSON

Tags: java, json, jtable

I have this method that takes data from a `DefaultTableModel` and converts it to a `JSONArray` using `org.json` library.

```
public static void writeTableToFileAsJSON(JTable table, String filePath) {
    table.setColumnSelectionInterval(1, table.getColumnCount() - 1);
    table.setRowSelectionInterval(0, table.getRowCount() - 1);
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    int rowCount = model.getRowCount();
    int columnCount = model.getColumnCount();

    boolean firstRow = true;
    try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(filePath)) {
        fw.write("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
            for (int j = 1; j < columnCount; j++) {
                Object value = model.getValueAt(i, j);

                String columnName = model.getColumnName(j);
                System.out.println(value + " - " + columnName);
                jsonObj.put(columnName, value);
            }
            fw.write(firstRow ? jsonObj.toString() : ("," + jsonObj.toString()));
            firstRow = false;
        }
        fw.write("]");
    } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
        //TODO handle ex
    }
}
```

What's strange is that depending on the data the JTable holds, the result from this method is correct. For example, a table like this:

```
+----+------------------+
| id | role_description |
+----+------------------+
|  1 | admin            |
|  2 | user             |
+----+------------------+
```

Will be successfully converted to:

```
[{"id":"1","role_description":"admin"},{"id":"2","role_description":"user"}]
```

But a table that has dates, for example:

```
+----------+------------------+------------+---------------------+
| store_id | manager_staff_id | address_id | last_update         |
+----------+------------------+------------+---------------------+
|        1 |                1 |          1 | 2006-02-15 04:57:12 |
|        2 |                2 |          2 | 2006-02-15 04:57:12 |
+----------+------------------+------------+---------------------+
```

Will be converted to:

```
[{"store_id":"1","manager_staff_id":"1","last_update":"2006-02-15 04:57:12","address_id":"1"},{"store_id":"2","manager_staff_id":"2","last_update":"2006-02-15 04:57:12","address_id":"2"}]
```

And I have no idea why the order is wrong.

Note: the reason why the `for` for columns starts at 1 is because the first column is reserved for row numbers and I don't want to include those in the JSON.

Comment: The second seens to be in the order, what the problem?

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos the second isn't in order. `last_update` should be the last column, but instead, it's before `address_id` in the JSON.

Comment: Why is this a problem?

Comment: I suppose the JSON is still valid, however, the order of elements is wrong and it shouldn't be.

Comment: I think it is a implementation of org.json lib, probably they store as a Set that does not keep order. Anyway.. if you use a custom TableModel with a List<StoreManagerObject> you can simply json serialize the list instead of getting all by x,y. Also custom TableModels give you the ability to store properties on the object of each row that is will not be visible at the JTable